# python-redmine filter issues by version due date

Tags: python, redmine, redmine-api, python-redmine

I need to filter issues where issue fixed_version due date is between two given date.
For example versions which they due_date is in current month.
I tried everything I could think of, but I couldn't figure it out.

I used below code now but It's too slow. It must be more precise

```
redmine = Redmine(REDMINE_PATH, username=REDMINE_USERNAME, password=REDMINE_PASSWORD)

issues = redmine.issue.filter(assigned_to_id=user_id, status_id=5)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little bit late but I was searching for the same for a long time.

```
issues_list = list(redmine.issue.filter(status_id='*', start_date='><start_date|end_date'))
```

But it works with Redmine version higher than 2.5